# Stepper Motor moving back and forth with emergency stop

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am trying to create a stepper motor that moves back and forth but will stop eminently when the safety  button is pressed.

I am using Arduino 1.8.13 and an Arduino UNO for this project.

```
#include <ezButton.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>


ezButton limitSwitch(A0); // create ezButton object that attach to pin A0;

AccelStepper stepper(AccelStepper::FULL4WIRE, 8, 9, 10, 11);

bool isStopped = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  limitSwitch.setDebounceTime(50); // set debounce time to 50 milliseconds

  stepper.setMaxSpeed(100.0);   // set the maximum speed
  stepper.setAcceleration(50.0); // set acceleration
  stepper.setSpeed(0);         // set initial speed
  stepper.setCurrentPosition(0); // set position
}



void loop() {
 
  limitSwitch.loop(); // MUST call the loop() function first

  if (limitSwitch.isPressed()) {
    Serial.println(F("The limit switch: TOUCHED"));
    isStopped = true;
  }
// if the button is pressed stop movement


if (isStopped == false) {

stepper.moveTo(500);
  while (stepper.currentPosition() != 300) // Full speed up to 300
    stepper.run();
  stepper.stop(); // Stop as fast as possible: sets new target
 
  // Now go backwards
  stepper.moveTo(-500);
  while (stepper.currentPosition() != 0) // Full speed basck to 0
    stepper.run();
  stepper.stop(); // Stop as fast as possible: sets new target

// if button is not pressed move motor back and forth. 
   
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("The stepper motor is STOPPED"));
  }
}
```

I have tried adding a while loop but any time I make the motor move back and forth the emergency stop will not work. it will however work when the motor is just continues in one direction.

Comment: First of all, do you get the `The limit switch: TOUCHED` and `The stepper motor is STOPPED` messages in the serial monitor?

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the button is pressed inside your while loops. It'll continue doing its thing in the while loops until the next time it checks if the button is pressed then it's back in the while loops again. So the code is doing exactly what you told it to do. You need to check for button press inside the while loops somehow.

Answer (score 0):

use interrupt function, like this :

```
int EMERGENCY_STOP_PIN = 2; // UNO support interrupt on pin d2 and d3

void setup() {
  pinMode (EMERGENCY_STOP, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(EMERGENCY_STOP_PIN), emergencyStop, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
//other codes...
}

void emergencyStop() {
//write your code to stop the motor...
}
```